# How to convert a float column to datetime with only year and month in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, to-date

I have a DATE column like this,

```
    DATE   CÓDIGO  ...          UNIDADE  VALOR
0  2009.06  10000.0  ...              NaN    NaN
1  2009.06  10100.0  ...    NÃO SE APLICA      .
2  2009.06  10101.0  ...               M2   0.46
3  2009.06  10102.0  ...               UN  15.15
```

I want to convert it to date format `%Y%m`.

Applying the code,

```
df['DATA'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DATA'], format='%Y.%m')
```

I get this,

```
0   1970-01-01 00:00:00.000002009
1   1970-01-01 00:00:00.000002009
2   1970-01-01 00:00:00.000002009
3   1970-01-01 00:00:00.000002009
4   1970-01-01 00:00:00.000002009
Name: DATA, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Convert to string first:

```
df['DATA'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DATA'].map('{:.2f}'.format), format='%Y.%m')
```

As it is, `pd.to_datetime` considers the float value is milliseconds since 1970.

Answer (score 2):

Adding `astype(str)`

```
pd.to_datetime(df['DATE'].astype(str), format='%Y.%m')
Out[710]: 
0   2009-06-01
1   2009-06-01
2   2009-06-01
3   2009-06-01
Name: DATE, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: I thought of that but I think controlling the format of the string conversion is safer :)